# C# get offset and length of a specific text format and then replace it with another text

Tags: c#, replace, pattern-matching

I have a text that contains a specific dynamics similar this:

```
var text = "Hello @[123456:Foo] :) Hello @[44444:Bar]";
```

I need to get the offset and the length of each pattern "@[aaa:bbb]"

so for '@[123456:Foo]' the offset is 6 and the length is 18
after getting these info I need to replace @[aaa:bbb] with bbb
so, after processing the text the output is offset, length, id, name for each @[aaa:bbb] and all @[aaa:bbb] replaced with bbb which is name

=> Hello Foo :) Hello Bar

my current code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Tests3
{
    internal struct EntityRange
    {
        // Offset of the entity
        public string Offset { get; set; }

        // Length of the entity
        public string Length { get; set; }
        public string EntityId { get; set; }

        public string EntityName { get; set; }

    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var text = "Hello @[123456:Foo] :) Hello @[44444:Bar]";
            var entitiesRangeList = GetEntityRangeList(text);
            text = ReplaceEntitiesWithName(text);

            // Queue  entitiesRangeList for processing..
        }

        private static string ReplaceEntitiesWithName(string text)
        {
            // replace @[aaa:bbb] with bbb

            return text;
        }

        private static List<EntityRange> GetEntityRangeList(string text)
        {
            var list = new List<EntityRange>();

            var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"@\[(\d+):([^][]*)]");

            foreach (Match m in matches)
            {
                var e = new EntityRange();

                e.EntityId = m.Groups[1].Value;
                e.EntityName = m.Groups[2].Value;

                // e.Offset = ?
               // e.Length = ?

            }

            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the documentation for the Group objects the regex match provides. Note all its wonderful fields/properties: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group?view=netframework-4.7.2#properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest declaring `Offset` and `Length` as `int` types:

```
internal struct EntityRange
{
    // Offset of the entity
    public int Offset { get; set; }

    // Length of the entity
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public string EntityId { get; set; }

    public string EntityName { get; set; }
}
```

Next, you may get the length with `Match.Length` property and the offset with `Match.Index` property, and do not forget to add the `e` to the list, `list.Add(e)`:

```
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    var e = new EntityRange();
    e.EntityId = m.Groups[1].Value;
    e.EntityName = m.Groups[2].Value;
    e.Offset = m.Index;                  // HERE
    e.Length = m.Groups[2].Value.Length; // HERE
    list.Add(e);                         // HERE
}
```

Replacing text is easy as you already captured the name:

```
private static string ReplaceEntitiesWithName(string text)
{
    return Regex.Replace(text, @"@\[\d+:([^][]*)]", "$1"); // replace @[aaa:bbb] with bbb
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/Kc1ChB):

```
var text = "Hello @[123456:Foo] :) Hello @[44444:Bar]";
var entitiesRangeList = GetEntityRangeList(text);
foreach (var e in entitiesRangeList)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Id={e.EntityId}, Name={e.EntityName}, Offset={e.Offset}, Length={e.Length}");
}
text = ReplaceEntitiesWithName(text);
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Output for the two matches found in the input string:

```
Id=123456, Name=Foo, Offset=6, Length=3
Id=44444, Name=Bar, Offset=29, Length=3
Hello Foo :) Hello Bar
```

Comment: @AronF Please consider accepting the answers that work for you. This way, you also say thanks and let other users that there is no need wasting their time on an SO post you need no further help with. If you want any more help with this, please drop  a comment.

Comment: I Just noticed that the function provides invalid length value. the length returned is the  text length which is not is what is needed. it should return the index of the match in the text and the length starting from the index to the end of the match..

Comment: @AronF Do you mean `e.Length = m.Length + m.Index;` ? See https://ideone.com/Kc1ChB

Comment: The current regex m.Length is returning the length of '@[aaa:bbb]' It should return only the length for 'bbb' only.

Comment: Ok I found it :D it works with: e.Length = m.Groups[2].Value.Length;